# How to Access Row in Pandas DataFrame With Boolean-Typed MultiIndex ("IndexError: Item wrong length 2 instead of 3.")

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a Pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex with all boolean-typed levels (example below). Trying to access specific rows of such a DataFrame by using a boolean label leads to an error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[False, False, 1],
                   [False, True,  2],
                   [True,  False, 3]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
df.set_index(["A", "B"], inplace=True)

print( df.loc[[False, False]] ) # IndexError: Item wrong length 2 instead of 3.
```

How can I access rows in a DataFrame with a a boolean-typed MultiIndex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice using [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html).

```
>>> df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[False, False]]
C    1
Name: (False, False), dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the row using a tuple.

```
print( df.loc[(False, False)] )
```

If you only have the values as a list, convert them to a tuple before accessing.

```
x = [False, False] # possibly result of some previous computation
print( df.loc[tuple(x)] )
```

---

## Background

Usually, rows in a Pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex can easily be [accessed using lists of values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label) like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], 
                   [4, 5, 6], 
                   [7, 8, 9]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
df.set_index(["A", "B"], inplace=True)
print( df.loc[[1, 2]] ) # prints first row of the DataFrame
```

The only thing that changed in this example from the question's is the data type of the MultiIndex. The issue with using a boolean data type for the MultiIndex is that it conflicts with boolean indexing.

[Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) allows selecting rows on the basis of some condition. For example, we could select all rows with a value in the C-column of less than 7 using `df.loc[df["C"] < 7]`. The inner condition results in an array of booleans, so this will be the same as `df.loc[[True, True, False]]`.

This obviously conflicts with the MultiIndex -- If both MultiIndex access using lists and boolean indexing were supported, there would be no way for Pandas to tell which of both is intended. By using a tuple it is made clear that the supplied value is in fact a label, not the result of evaluating some condition.